# SQL Server: Running Multiple Select Queries in same .SQL file

Tags: sql, sql-server

I've been a long time Oracle user and generally if I needed to run multiple SQL queries, I would end one with a semicolon (;) and then start the new one. Example:

```
Select * from dual;
Select * myTable;
```

Questions:

1. How can I go about running the whole script in SQL Server?
2. How can
   I replicate the behavior where if I put the cursor on the second SQL
   statement and press F9 (or F5 in SQL Server) that only the second
   statement runs? In other words, if I put my cursor anywhere in the
   current SQL statement and press the Execute button, it will run
   everything after the previous semicolon (;)?

Thank you.

Comment: You can run multiple queries in SQL Server by separating them with a colon.  Try doing this in SQL Server Management Studio.

Comment: For question 2, you probably can't.  Highlighting the sql block and pressing F5 might be as good as it gets.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Sql Server is very permisive and you just need to write the statements in the text editor window and hit run to execut everything, you don't need anything explicit to separate them. That's if you use Management Studio. In Management Studio you can also separate batches using the GO keyword.
2. If you want to run a specific statement in the text editor window you just need to highlight the statements you want to run and then hit run with them highlighted and Management Studio will execute only the selected statement.